# Check_mk and wildcards

Tags: monitoring, check-mk

I've successfully set up check_mk 1.28 via OMD, which I know supports wildcards and regex for assignment of hosts/services to groups. I've tested the wildcards in the search box successfully, but the groups are not being populated and are showing up as "ineffective".

[image]
[image]

All searches I've seen so far say that this should be possible, but I can't determine what is missing. Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems few days ago and in my case works in this way `~.\*omd.\*`. Tested on check_mk server 1.2.6p12